# Google Cardboard SDK not containing GvrViewerMain

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

Just downloaded the latest Google Cardboard SDK for Unity from here:
https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/download

All the tutorials I have seen (including Google's own) talk about dragging the GvrViewerMain prefab into the Hierachy.  However, I have searched all the google VR assets included in the download and GvrViewerMain is not present.  Anyone know where I can download this from or which Prefab to use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [*Google VR SDK for Unity v1.50*](https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/release-notes?pageId=113417735779738828429) release note, this version and any other version above it removed *GvrViewerMain*.

It has been replaced with *GvrEditorEmulator*.

You can find this [in](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/tree/master/GoogleVR/Prefabs) *GoogleVR/Prefabs/GvrEditorEmulator.prefab*.

Comment: Thanks.  I just took the GvrEditorEmulator and moved it into my hierarchy.  I then dragged my existing camera into the GvrEditorEmulator camera property.  When I ran the game from unity I didnt see 2 views (like we used to), but when I ran the game from an iphone (having added VR cardboard to the Build Settings > Player Settings section for iOS) it all just worked.

Comment: I've also noticed this problem and have seen seen it here since last week. I think you should create an issue on the [Github](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues) link of this project. They will fix it if it is a bug.

Comment: Turns out its by design.  They have stopped showing the stereoscopic view except on devices... pretty annoying.

Comment: I always hated the stereoscopic view in the Editor. I think I am on their side on this one. You will get use to it soon. It's just there to make it easier to program your game.

Answer (score 1):

They removed it. And updated with just script.
Add game object and apply script on it.
It will create camera at run time.

You can see this for entire detail.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q7Ce_ZefGO8&t=132s